# How to get the JavaScript display results "on click" query to display ALL results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an excel spreadsheet compiling all responses from an online survey on Google Chrome, there are over 500 entries and to click on each entry to get the results would take forever.

I've pinpointed the problem on the Google Chrome > Inspect > Elements at the point with the multiple display results onclick. Is there any way to remove the onclick to be able to download or copy-paste all the results at once?

I've attached a picture below:

[https://imgur.com/wyxoRjN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX8wt.jpg)

I would appreciate any advice on how best to do this! Apologies in advance as I have absolutely no programming experience so I might not get all the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

You should check with the online survey service since there should be a way to **export your results to csv** (csv can be opened in excel). (Author indicated there was no way)

Before using website scraping code, make sure that the service is alright with you grabbing the data that way. The code should not be scraped for malicious intent or means that break terms of the agreement.

IF the structure that you provided is consistent then you should be able to copy the code below (or from the javascript pane in the fiddle), run it in the console on the page with the data (F12, console tab in chrome), the data should print to the console where you can copy it, and then use an online tool([like this](https://json-csv.com/)) to convert it from json to csv for excel.

```
var getData = () => {
  var table = document.getElementById('table_survey'); // get table
  var data = []; // holds all the data

  for (i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {  //loops through rows  
    var pieceOfData = {}

    var cells = table.rows.item(i).cells; //gets cells
    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) { //loops through each cell

      var cellVal = cells.item(j).innerHTML; // get piece of data

      // store data in object dependent on index
      //assumes only 4 <td>s with valid data
      switch (j) {
        case 0:
          pieceOfData.id = cellVal
        case 1:
          pieceOfData.data1 = cellVal
        case 2:
          pieceOfData.data2 = cellVal
        case 3:
          pieceOfData.day = cellVal
      }
    }
    data.push(pieceOfData); // add data object to array
  }

  return data; // return all the data
}

var allData = getData(); // puts all the data in a variable
console.log(allData); // print data to console
```

My Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m852hge8/

Comment: The online service is http://leisure-net.org/. I have already written to them enquiring about exporting results to csv and was informed that that feature doesn't exist at the moment and that until then I can only manually input the data individually.

Comment: I've added a image here (https://imgur.com/a/Ojxkw) with the code displayed. Not sure if that's what you're referring to, but assuming it is, don't think the endpoint is displayed.

Comment: That isn't as easy as an endpoint, but that should be definitely scrapable. Give me a few minutes to update my answer. Could you provide a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) of the table with a sampling of the rows?

Comment: @ThePanzer there is no need to extract all the data. You have much simpler solutions.

Comment: @Lagos Arpad 13 It's my understanding that he does need to extract all the data since he needs it to be compatible with excel. To just remove the onclick functions would still leave the data in an HTML structure which excel does not recognize.

Answer (score 0):

In my view the easiest, low-tech way to do this is to paste the whole thing in a text editor such as Notepad++ (which is free), and do a lot of "replace all" to remove what you don't want (by replacing by blank).

For example replace "tr onclick="displayResults(" by "" (i.e. blank)

Comment: Would work, just very manual and very error prone since there are over 500 pieces of data. How do you know that a replace all would not replace part of the data you want to preserve unless you want to double check all 500 pieces of data everytime you make a replace all.

Comment: Well it's unlikely that the data, which in this case are numbers, will contain what we are trying to get rid of, in this case code :) but i agree it's very low tech and not always suitable.

Comment: @Alex Bergeret your right for the numbers and DateTime as long as you know the format. I'm not sure if the two string values that needed extracting were based on a static list or free form from the user. free form from user = data hell. lol

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to switch off the Javascript of your browser while you work on the CSV and swith it back on when you are finished. The `onclick` is executing Javascript and if it is switched off for your browser, then it will not be executed.

This should work, however, if Javascript is needed to display the data you need to extract, then you need Javascript to be switched on, but you can override `displayResult` to be a dummy function, so you will not experience the problematic behavior when you click in your browser console:

```
displayResult = function() {};
```

This should work, but if, for some reason `displayResult` is redefined, then you can remove the `onclick` of each element. If there are too many elements for manual execution, then you can execute something like this in your console:

```
var survey = document.querySelectorAll("#table-survey tr");
for (var index = 0; index < survey.length; index++) {
    survey[index].onclick = "";
}
```